# finding value of formula.

Tags: calculus, finite-differences

I am little bit confusing how to calculate $δβ/δρ$ value if I have set of values like this.

I have the values of $β$ and $ρ$ like this.
$$ \begin{array}{l|l}
    β     &     ρ\\ \hline
    0,324  &   0,687\\
    0,322  &   0,695\\
    0,319  &   0,721\\
    0,317 &    0,759\\
    0,316  &   0,798
\end{array} $$
from the above set of values i need to calculate this "$δβ/δρ$" $=$ ?

Can anyone explain me how to calculate it in microsoft excel or normal method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$ is the change in $\beta$ between two lines divided by the difference in $\rho$ in the same two lines.  So for the first two, you would have $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}=\frac{0.324-0.322}{0.687-0.695}=\frac{0.002}{-0.008}=\frac {-1}4$  If these are measured values, the error is quite large because of the subtraction.

Comment: just first two values is enough! to calculate $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$. Is it same for all values I mean if i calculate last two values then i am getting different.

Comment: $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$ varies.  You will get a different value for each pair of lines.  If $\rho$ were time and $\beta$ were distance, $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$ is the average speed during the time interval.  That can change from one timestep to the next if you are accelerating/decelerating.  With your data it is negative-you are decelerating.

Comment: What can I use if i have different value for each pair of lines. I have the above dataset then i need calculate $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$ and i need to use it in another formula.

Comment: You have two choices.  First, you can calculate it for each pair of lines, which will give four values for $\frac {\delta \beta}{\delta \rho}$.  You can then put your formula that uses it in four cells in a column and use each value in the corresponding row.  Second, you can use the formula I gave on the top and bottom lines, getting $\frac {-.008}{.111}\approx -0.072$ and use that.  It is the average value over all your data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Ross Millikan's excellent answer, to compute in Excel, suppose your data is in columns A,B, in rows 2-6 (row 1 is the header row).  Into entry C2 put "=A2-A3", then copy this into C3-C5 (Excel will update the references as needed).  Into entry D2 put "=B2-B3", then copy this into D3-D5. (the previous two steps can be combined).  Into entry E2 put "=C2/D2", then copy this into E3-E5.